# Shipping SQLite dbs with Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to be able to include an sqlite file with a Chrome Extension, and make it so that the extension can perform read/write ops on that db. I will be using it for process intercom (by lack of alternatives) so I can override configs / pass command-line parameters / etc. to Chrome.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. 
Partially solved. Chrome supports passing `--user-data-dir=%appdata%/whatever`

From where in my external application I can access `%appdata%/Whatever/databases/Databases.db`, open `Databases` table, filter by origin, get an `ID` and open `%appdata%/Whatever/databases/origin/ID`. It's somewhat hackish but will do.

What puzzles me now is that:

- It did't yell at my attempt to `openDatabase('X','1.0','plm',100*1024*1024);` I was expecting some resistance at asking 100MB without "unlimitedStorage" permission
- not sure what the _0 postfix in origin
- `chrome-extension_bhapcikibejcipnnpimookjaibhlddfd_0` might be inconsistent; is it safe to hardcode in the other application?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want by shipping a file AFAIK, but since WebSQL in Chrome is essentially SQLite you could ship your "database" as JSON datastructures in your code, and use that to initialize a WebSQL instance in Chrome when you initialize the WebSQL database for your application/extension.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is very strict when it comes to use outside files.

Anyway, Chrome extensions should use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html). Something like:

```
localStorage["varName"] = data;
```

or

```
localStorage.varName = data
```

and

```
var data = localStorage.varName
```

Check for more info [here](http://julianapena.com/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-2-options-and-localstorage/)

Comment: I don't think it helps. I need Chrome to communicate the precise location of that respective file, which involves writing its path into a file which I don't have the path to which would involve [...] so on.